# Get the value of a variable in page1.php in page2.php

Tags: php, random

I have a question about how I can access the value from a variable from one page on another one.

I have a registration script and the registration form is on my homepage. I want to dynamically create a random name for every input field (change the value of the name attribute). The current name attribute for the input is just `firstName`, but I want it to be like `firstName_345635`. The `345635` is a randomly generated number and will change everytime the page refreshes.

Here is my random number variable:

```
$firstNameInputName = 'firstName_' . rand(10000, 50000);
```

The output becomes: `firstName_[randomNumer]`.

The problem is, the register.php has all the post variables to get the form data. What I have now is this:

```
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"]);
```

I need to get the value from the random number variables from the homepage and instead of giving the `$firstname` variable the name `firstName`, it should get the name that the random number generating variable has produced on the homepage.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Create a variable for your `rand()` then concatenate it to your other variable(s). I.e.: `$rand_fname = rand(10000, 50000);` etc. you can then use `$rand_fname` as you wish after.

Comment: You can get the keys that are present at `$_POST` with `array_keys($_POSTS)` and iterate over them (with a `foreach`, for example). If that is not good enough you will have to use sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a **session** (or cookies) var to save this dynamic name.

**Approach 1**. Session (or cookies)

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$customCode = rand(5, 15);
$_SESSION['customCode'] = $customCode; ?>

<form action="page2.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstName_<?php echo $customCode; ?>" />
</form>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$customCode = $_SESSION['customCode']; ?>
$firstName = $_POST['firstName_'.$customCode];
```

**Approach 2**. You can put a input hidden field in your form like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="customCode" value="345635" />
```

And get it in second page like:

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstName_'.$_POST['customCode']];
```

**Approach 3**. You can iterate over your $_POST array to get firstName like:

```
foreach($_POST in $key => $value) {
 if(strpos($key, "firstName")) {
  $firstName = $value;
 }
}
```

Comment: Remember: to use `$_SESSION` you have to call `session_start()` (it also good to learn about other session related functions). This is a common gotcha for beginners.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! I've used the hidden fields method and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), session variables are superglobal variables which means you can use them in different files as long as its the same session, to use them you need to start the session at every page you'll use them in, also, starting the session has to be done before any output is shown.

Ex (registeration page):

```
<?php
session_start();
/**
** HTML AND FORM HERE WHATEVER ELSE YOU NEED TO DISPLAY
**/
$_SESSION['FirstName'] = $firstNameInputName;
?>
```

Ex (processing page):

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_POST[$_SESSION['FirstName']]; // Output: Whatever was entered inside the field
?>
```

Comment: And how can I do this with multiple input fields (I have four now)?